# pass 3 value to sub : Too many arguments for

Tags: perl

I have an input like this:

```
100 200 A_30:120,A_140:180,B_180:220
100 300 A_70:220,B_130:300,A_190:200,A_60:300
```

I want to count number of A or B in each line and also compare range of A or B in each line with the range in two first column and return the length of intersection. e.g. output for first line:  `A:2 A_length:40 B:1 B_length:20`

```
while(<>){
chomp($_);
my @line = split("\t| ", $_);
my $col1 = $line[0];
my $col2 = $line[1];
my @col3 = split(",",$line[2]);
my $A=0;
my $B=0;
my $A_length=0;
my $B_length=0;
for my $i (0 .. @col3-1){
        my $col3 = $col3[$i];
        if ($col3 =~ /A/){
                my $length=0;
                $length = range ($col3,$col1,$col2);
                $A_length = $A_length+$length;
                $A++;
                    }
        if ($col3 =~ /B/){
                my $length=0;
                $length = range ($col3,$col1,$col2);
                $B_length = $B_length+$length;
                $B++;
                    }
                $i++;
}
                print("#A: ",$A,"\t","length_A: ",$A_length,"\t","#B: ",$B,"\t","length_B: ",$B_length,"\n");}




sub range {
                my ($col3, $col1, $col2)  = ($_[0],$_[1],$_[2]);
                my @sub = split(":|_", $col3);
                my $sub_strt = $sub[1];
                my $sub_end = $sub[2];
                my $sub_length;
                if (($col1 >= $sub_strt) && ($col2 >= $sub_end)){
                      $sub_length = ($sub_end) - ($col1);}
                if (($col1 >= $sub_strt) && ($col2 >= $sub_end)){
                      $sub_length = ($col2) - ($col1);}
                if(($col1 <= $sub_strt) && ($col2 >= $sub_end)){
                      $sub_length = ($sub_end) - ($sub_strt);}
                if(($col1 <= $sub_strt) && ($col2 <= $sub_end)){
                      $sub_length = ($col2) - ($sub_strt);}
                return $sub_length;
}
```

I FIXED IT :)

Comment: What do you think the [`length`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#length) function is supposed to do?

Comment: in line one: we have an range (100-200), and in col3 we have 2 A's. intersection of A_30:120 with 100-200 is 20 and intersection of another A in col3 (A_140:180) with 100-200 gives 40, so A:2 A_length:20+40

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl already has a builtin [`length`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#length) function, which only takes one argument. As perl is compiling your script and gets to your `length` function call, it doesn't know about the `sub length { ... }` that you have defined later in the script, so it complains that you are using the builtin `length` function incorrectly.

How to fix this? This is Perl, so there are many ways

1. name your function something else. Making a function with the same name as a Perl builtin function is usually a bad idea
2. Call your function with the `&` sigil: `my $length = &length($col3,$col1,$col2);` That will be enough of a hint to the compiler that your function call does not refer to the builtin function.
3. Qualify your function call with a package name, in this case `main::length($col3,$col1,$col2)` or just `::length($col3,$col1,$col2)`.

Note that even if Perl did know about the `length` function you defined (you could get Perl to know by moving the `sub length { ... }` definition to the top of the script, for example), the function call would still be ambiguous to the compiler, the compiler would emit a warning like

```
Ambiguous call resolved as CORE::length(), qualify as such or use & at ...
```

and your script would still fail to compile. Here `CORE::length` would mean that Perl is resolving the ambiguity in favor of the builtin function.